# Table of animations not showing, but individual animations work fine

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, animation

I'm trying to make a bunch of animated plots that sit next to eachother.  If I do:

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[3*\[Pi]* x ]*Cos[3*t/2], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

I get an individual animation that works great, and if I do:

```
Table[Plot[Sin[n*\[Pi]* x ]*Cos[n*0/2], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {n, 1, 4}]
```

I get a nice row of different functions.  But, if I try to combine them using:

```
Table[Animate[Plot[Sin[n*\[Pi]* x ]*Cos[n*t/2], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 10}], {n, 1, 4}]
```

Then I just get 4 empty plots, with an animation running that does nothing.   What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try  `Table[With[{n = n}, 
  Animate[Plot[Sin[n*\[Pi]*x]*Cos[n*t/2], {x, 0, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 10}]], {n, 1, 4}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thanks!  This solution works perfect.  I'm a little confused why With is required when I stack Table and Animate, but not when I just use one of them.   Also, I though that when a variable appeared light green rather than blue, it meant that the engine understood that it was a local variable, and in my statement that wasn't working they were all light green.  What does it mean when the color of a variable changes in an expression?

Also, how do I acknowledge a good answer if it's in the comments rather than a separate post?